# jQuery ajax calls (.get, .post., .load etc), return data and IE problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, post, get

This is not a question by itself as my notice while working with jQuery 1.3.2

I've spent quite some time researching, looking and finally testing (should have done that in the first place) and here is what I've found:

Let's say you have a small file (call it example.php):

```html
 <div>Hello world</div></div>
```

And in the main file you make this specific call

```html
<div class="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('example.php', function(data){
     $('.result').html(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

Now this will work on every single browser except for IE8/7 (haven't tested it on IE9). That is because the received data is not parsed as html, though it receives it properly. The only thing to do to solve this is to remove the additiona  tag from the "example.php" file. This will fix the problem.
This might seem simple, but when you've got complex *.php / *.html files on the get call, this could get quite messy and a nightmare to resolve.

**NOTE:**
I tried searching stackoverflow for this specific problem, but did not find a definite answer or solution for this. Hence I've posted this specific problem and solution to it. Considering myself quite a *NOOB* at this, if anyone points out that there is already an explanation for this, tell me and I will remove this post.

Comment: maybe try to use $.ajax and set the data type to "text" instead of using $.get?

Comment: First, the current jQuery version is `1.6`, not `1.3.2`. Second, if your returned html code is like the one you provided (i.e. `<div>Hello world</div></div>`), then you should start validating your returned HTML, because that's not a valid one. _Hint_ there are two `div` closing tags.

Comment: @Shef i think he knows that and he is actually asking how to avoid validating the html in the first place

Comment: I know that the current version is 1.6, but bear in mind, that a lot of websites and some of the plugins still use the 1.3.2 or 1.4 versions of jQuery (i.e. jQuery Tools collection of plugins). This is a notice rather than a question as I've found the problem in this specific area and if anyone finds themselves in a similar situation, it is a good idea to check the tags and for html validity.
Thank you for you comments BTW.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.result').html("");
$('.result').append(data);
```

it might remove invalid tags
but consider using iframe for container `.result`

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work really. IE doesn't recognise the "data" variable as html

Comment: well i suppose IE doesn't get fooled so easily

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control over an ajax call using jQuery you should use the $.ajax call itself and manipulate the parameters.  Specifically setting the dataType: to 'text'

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Nice one, I will try to test this.

Comment: Tried out this part. IE literally starts to believe that the thing is data sent is text and displays it as literal text. The method of cleaning up the html (removing </div> or any other closing tags) propably is the best way to go for now.